# Can't add image texture to a flat plane, renders white.

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to add a simple image of grass to a flat plane. I have copy pasted a free blender object of grass onto a new file in order to integrate it with other objects, have linked the image in the texture section, through the node editor, have unwrapped the plane, and in UV editor it appears as a square grid with no texture on it, with one corner orange and the rest grey. If I select the image in the UV editor the grid becomes rectangular, about twice as long as the square, and has the image applied to it.

If I render, it looks totally white. What's going on? I wish I could just copy paste the other objects onto the original grass file, but when I do that they appear as negative space in the render, so I figured the easier problem to fix is this one.

Thank you!!

Comment: Copy pasting should be used sparingly, it is not a proper way to bring things into a file, texture paths might be messed up and you end up with uncessary duplication. Use *File> Link* or *File> Append* instead.

Comment: Also have you created a material using your texture? UV unwrapping is **not** the same as applying a texture.

Comment: I think you are going to have to post the .blend file or at least some screen shots for this one. It is not possible to say without seeing it.